# Building a full featured gallery with voting system

Tags: 7, entities, rating

I'm looking for a way to build a simple gallery node type in Drupal, with vote (*with [Votingapi](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi) and [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar)*)per image enabled. (*1 vote per image, per node, per user, and users are able to vote on any image in the node*).
As simple as it looks, I'm unable to build a simple proof of concept of what I'm trying to achieve.

Here's [a mockup](https://moqups.com/d.paolino@gmail.com/5nFKGF3s) of how I see the thing, and here's how I see the thing in Drupal.
A content type 'Gallery' these following fields:

- Title
- Body
- Field Collection (multiple):

  - Image (single)
  - Fivestar rating

I succeeded to do it and now, to compute the results, I would like to get the results per node.
However, if you look into the votingapi_vote table, the only data for a vote are:

```
MariaDB [voting]> SELECT * FROM votingapi_vote;
+---------+-----------------------+-----------+-------+------------+------+-----+------------+-------------+
| vote_id | entity_type           | entity_id | value | value_type | tag  | uid | timestamp  | vote_source |
+---------+-----------------------+-----------+-------+------------+------+-----+------------+-------------+
|      10 | field_collection_item |         2 |    80 | percent    | vote |   1 | 1455270089 | 127.0.0.1   |
|      13 | field_collection_item |         3 |    60 | percent    | vote |   1 | 1455271926 | 127.0.0.1   |
|      15 | field_collection_item |         1 |    80 | percent    | vote |   1 | 1455272041 | 127.0.0.1   |
+---------+-----------------------+-----------+-------+------------+------+-----+------------+-------------+
```

It is impossible to retrieve data from the parent node because it simple doesn't exists in the DB.

It looks like we could change tags dynamically, so I hooked into fivestar to generate dynamic tags, but it gets blocked in [_fivestar_cast_vote()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/fivestar/tree/fivestar.module?h=7.x-2.x#n153), especially in [fivestar_validate_target()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/fivestar/tree/fivestar.module?h=7.x-2.x#n287), and I'm unable to generate tags dynamically.

I also tried to hook into Votingapi using [hook_votingapi_preset_votes_alter()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/votingapi/tree/votingapi.module#n137) but if you're using Fivestar with the AJAX widget, it's impossible to get information on the current node using [menu_get_object()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7). So I'm still stuck.

Now I'm trying to look for another solution, if you have ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Would it be an option to use rules to apply a vote from the field collection item onto the parent item?

Comment: That would be way too complicated. We should be able to use the 'tag' field instead. Fivestar doesn't allow to use dynamic tags, so, I don't know what to do yet. I'll see.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the [Answers](https://www.drupal.org/project/answers) module for such gallery, whereas you'd replace your field collection with "answer"-nodes, and the question-nodes would be used for the title and body. For more details, have a look at my answer to [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118190/community-website-user-rating-based-on-votes-in-node-statistics/201339#201339).

Answer (score 0):

> 1 vote per image, per node, per user, and users are able to vote on
>   any image in the node

I don't fully understand the use case here; it might be easier to visualise the scenario with a fuller explanation?

At a guess, the issue might revolve around the use of `field collection` module here? I'm not a wizard at the internals of that, but personally in this situation I usually manage this with a container/item setup:

- Gallery (node/entity)

  - Image (node/entity)
  - Image
- Gallery

  - Image
  - Image

I then relate these either with `entity_reference` or I guess you could use `inline entity form`, depends. I don't know if there is anything that precludes you from doing it this way, but I think you're more likely to have better data from votingapi et al like this? Probably using two content types is going to give more joy than entities for that reason.

This is all from a site builder perspective, where using this kind of setup generally means I have to write as near to zero code as possible!

Comment: Here's [a simple mockup](https://moqups.com/d.paolino@gmail.com/5nFKGF3s) of what I'm trying to do.
And yes, users are able to vote on any images, once. Then can vote on all the images or only some of them.
To compute the values, we must use a [bayesian computation](https://www.drupal.org/project/votingapi_bayesian).

Comment: The thing is that to compute the bayesian computation, you have to use all the values of the vote of the node. This is why we need a tag per vote.